# Dynamic nested sum

Tags: dynamic, summation

I would like to dynamically create nested sums with a dynamic number of parameters aswell.
We do know the number of variables. Lets say we have 3 Variables with S being an array:
$$
i=(1,\dots,m), j=(1,\dots,n),k=(1,\dots,l)
$$
Therefore we have two nested Sums each:
$$
    f_i=\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^l S(i,j,k)\\ g_j=\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{k=1}^l S(i,j,k)\\ h_k=\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n S(i,j,k)
$$

With a different set of data we might have 4 variables:
$$
i=(1,\dots,m), j=(1,\dots,n),k=(1,\dots,l),o=(1,\dots,t)
$$

with 3 nested sums each:

$$
    f_i=\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^l\sum_{o=1}^t S(i,j,k,o)\\ g_j=\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{k=1}^l\sum_{o=1}^t S(i,j,k,o)\\ h_k=\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{o=1}^t S(i,j,k,o)\\ r_o=\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^l\sum_{i=1}^m S(i,j,k,o)
$$
Is there any way to create these nested sums dynamically considering we know the number of parameters?
This is what I've gotten so far but I don't know how to get the list part `S[[k[1],k[2],k[3]]]` dynamically:

```
varrange={4,4,4};
numbervars=Length[varrange];
iterator = Table[{k[m], 1, varrange[[m]]}, {m, numbervars}]
{{k[1], 1, 4}, {k[2], 1, 4}, {k[3], 1, 4}}

Sum[S[[k[1], k[2], k[3]]], Evaluate[Sequence @@ iterator]]
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there ...

If

```
ind = First/@iterator;
(*{k[1], k[2], k[3]} *)
```

then

**if S is a function S[...]**

```
Sum[S[Sequence @@ ind], Evaluate[Sequence @@ iterator]]
```

or the equivalent but more elegant and compact form

```
Sum[S @@ ind, ##] & @@ iterator
Sum[S @@ First /@ {##}, ##] & @@ iterator
```

give

[image]

**If S is an array, S[[...]]**

just replace S[...] by S[[...]] :

```
Sum[S[[Sequence @@ ind]], Evaluate[Sequence @@ iterator]]
```

or use the equivalent compact form :

```
Sum[S[[##]] & @@ ind, ##] & @@ iterator
Sum[S[[##]] & @@ First /@ {##}, ##] & @@ iterator
```

or also :

```
s[i__]:=S[[i]];
Sum[s[[##]] & @@ ind, ##] & @@ iterator
```

or this might be useful to visually check the summation before evaluation :

```
check = Sum[foo[[##]] & @@ ind, ##] & @@ iterator
check  /. foo[x__] :> S[[x]]
```

Comment: i'm not sure how this accesses the list? dont i need dbl brackets S[[1,1,1]] + S[[1,1,2]] + ...

Comment: If S is a function, then use S[...], If S is an array use S[[...]].

Comment: oh wow i'm stupid :) ye great that works. highly appreciated

Comment: @SquareOne you could also do second line as `Sum[S @@ ind, ##] & @@ iterator`

Comment: @ubpdqn And `Sum[S[[##]] & @@ ind, ##] & @@ iterator` when S is an array ;) -> i will include these in the post ;)

Comment: @SquareOne yes...I have +1, you provided the direction to get OP to achieve his aim :)

Answer (score 1):

```
fun[list_, f_] := Total[f @@@ Tuples[list]]
```

For example:

```
fun[{Range[3], Range[4], Range[5]}, S]
```

yields:

```
(* S[1, 1, 1] + S[1, 1, 2] + S[1, 1, 3] + S[1, 1, 4] + S[1, 1, 5] + 
 S[1, 2, 1] + S[1, 2, 2] + S[1, 2, 3] + S[1, 2, 4] + S[1, 2, 5] + 
 S[1, 3, 1] + S[1, 3, 2] + S[1, 3, 3] + S[1, 3, 4] + S[1, 3, 5] + 
 S[1, 4, 1] + S[1, 4, 2] + S[1, 4, 3] + S[1, 4, 4] + S[1, 4, 5] + 
 S[2, 1, 1] + S[2, 1, 2] + S[2, 1, 3] + S[2, 1, 4] + S[2, 1, 5] + 
 S[2, 2, 1] + S[2, 2, 2] + S[2, 2, 3] + S[2, 2, 4] + S[2, 2, 5] + 
 S[2, 3, 1] + S[2, 3, 2] + S[2, 3, 3] + S[2, 3, 4] + S[2, 3, 5] + 
 S[2, 4, 1] + S[2, 4, 2] + S[2, 4, 3] + S[2, 4, 4] + S[2, 4, 5] + 
 S[3, 1, 1] + S[3, 1, 2] + S[3, 1, 3] + S[3, 1, 4] + S[3, 1, 5] + 
 S[3, 2, 1] + S[3, 2, 2] + S[3, 2, 3] + S[3, 2, 4] + S[3, 2, 5] + 
 S[3, 3, 1] + S[3, 3, 2] + S[3, 3, 3] + S[3, 3, 4] + S[3, 3, 5] + 
 S[3, 4, 1] + S[3, 4, 2] + S[3, 4, 3] + S[3, 4, 4] + S[3, 4, 5] *)
```

**UPDATE**
after clarification (see comment):

```
funa[list_, array_] := Total[array[[##]] & @@@ Tuples[list]]
```

For examples:

```
 mat={{{8, 8, 8, 10}, {8, 7, 9, 4}, {6, 9, 3, 6}}, {{3, 5, 9, 6}, {2, 3, 5,
    9}, {8, 1, 6, 7}}}
```

testing:

```
funa[#, mat] & /@ {{Range[2]}, {Range[2], Range[3]}, {Range[2], 
   Range[3], Range[4]}}
```

yields:

```
{{{11, 13, 17, 16}, {10, 10, 14, 13}, {14, 10, 9, 13}}, {35, 33, 40, 
  42}, 150}
```

Noting the accepted answer (in which the `Part` comment appears irrelevant but nicely assists in getting code to work, you could also do:

```
func[varr_, f_] := With[{lst = Range /@ varr},
  Total[f @@@ Tuples[lst]]]
```

with the test example: `func[{4,4,4},S]`

Comment: not sure if that works when S is a 3-dimensional array so it would have to be accessed S[[1,1,1]]?

Comment: @Ocin from your question I erroneously assumed that `S` is a function of multiple arguments rather than an array. It is a small to change.